Mongodb occasional 500 error in production
I’m working on a nextjs project (https://recurwallet.vercel.app) and it connects to mongodb atlas.
It works perfectly in localhost but in Vercel deployment occasionally I get this error with next auth.
I don’t think the user session expired because sometimes I’ve tried the application after much longer and it seemed to still be active
Can’t understand what the issue could be. Pasting logs below:
[GET] /api/auth/session?nxtPnextauth=session status=500
Unhandled Rejection: MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:278:38)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
servers: Map(3) {
'ac-6f2vd8f-shard-00-02.wo509tr.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
'ac-6f2vd8f-shard-00-00.wo509tr.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
'ac-6f2vd8f-shard-00-01.wo509tr.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
},
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: 'atlas-r1jdn2-shard-0',
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
},
code: undefined,
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
Node.js process exited with exit status: 128. The logs above can help with debugging the issue.
Unknown application error occurred


I am also facing the same issue.

you probably did not configure whitelisting ip in mongodb. Whitelist Ip allows access to network services only to those on a pre-approved list of IP addresses.
In production, you created a new cloud mongodb atlas and your app is connecting to that. As far as I know, when you create a new cluster in MongoDB Atlas, there are no IP addresses whitelisted by default.
if you add 0.0.0.0/0 to the whitelist, it will allow anyone from anywhere


Why would an unwhitelisted up cause an "occasional" auth failure? I'd expect a consistent auth failure.

this is the error message MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 3000

Yes but the OP says occasionally I get this error with next auth; it usually works, but then sometimes it doesn't (possibly due to the server selection timeout). If the issue was the IP whitelist, I'd expect it to never work.

Yes exactly I already have added 0.0.0.0/0 to my whitelisted ip addresses.. and yes it only fails occasionally and not everytime. I also notice the user session object return undefined in console
